# Sort structs by char array (name) (c++)

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, char, qsort

I have a struct which looks like this:

```
struct employee
{
    char name[21], surname[21];
    unsigned int salary;

}employees[20];
```

My question is, how would I sort this array of structs by the field "name", sorting them alphabetically.

I've seen people use `sort()` or `qsort()`, but I don't know how to make the `compare()` that you usually have to make for those sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a lambda expression as for example

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

//...

std::sort( std::begin( employees ), std::end( employees ),
           []( const auto &em1, const auto &em2 )
           {
               return strcmp( em1.name, em2.name ) < 0;
           } );
```

Instead of the character arrays used as data members in the structure it is much better to use objects of the type `std::string`.

Comment: Another approach would be to use an ordered map

Comment: This is correct. Ideally `name` would be a `std::string` to avoid needing the `strcmp`.